# .NET WebRequest using SSL - can't get past proxy

Tags: .net, ssl, proxy

I'm trying to make a request to a website from a .NET client using SSL and I'm struggling to get past the corporate proxy. It keeps giving me `403 Forbidden: Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
string uri = "https://www.website.com";
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.KeepAlive = true;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Method = "GET";
response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Every source on the subject seems to claim that putting `<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />` in your App.config is the magic bullet for this problem, but it doesn't seem to make a difference here. It seems to me that this would have the same effect as the assignment to `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials` above, but if I remove the assignment and keep the declaration in App.config I get an error `407: Proxy authentication required` instead.

I've taken a look at the actual traffic in Fiddler. Both transactions consist of three messages; the first two result in 407, which I assume is correct. Where IE receives the status `200: Connection established` in the last message, my program instead gets `403: Forbidden`.

Looking at the contents in detail, the only differences are that IE uses HTTP/1.0 instead of 1.1 and supplies some more information like User-Agent, Content-Length, DNT and Pragma. I would guess that these are unrelated to the problem, and I haven't figured out how to set them anyway.

The behaviour is the same regardless of what URL I try to connect to. If I bypass the proxy server it works.

Could somebody shed some light on this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Details from Fiddler follow. This will get lengthy, but here we go:

The .NET client issues the following message:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.website.com
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

With IE, the first message is:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: www.website.com
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
```

Reply from the proxy in both cases is:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE
Proxy-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Authenticate: BASIC realm="[...]"
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: close
Set-Cookie: [...]; Path=/
Connection: close
Content-Length: 849
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

["Credentials are missing."]
```

Negotiate message from .NET:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate [...]
Host: www.website.com
```

Compare to IE:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: www.website.com
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate [...]
Content-Length: 0
```

Challenge from proxy:

```
HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required
Proxy-Authenticate: NEGOTIATE [...]
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Set-Cookie: ...; Path=/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 866
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

["Another round of authentication is required."]
```

And finally, the challenge response from .NET:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate [...]
Host: www.website.com
```

From IE:

```
CONNECT www.website.com:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)
Host: www.website.com
Proxy-Authorization: Negotiate [...]
DNT: 1
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.1 (TLS/1.0)
Random: 54 FE A4 42 3B B5 14 66 0C F1 CE 6B BA 79 B8 EE B7 86 B1 4B 6E 76 F0 42 C6 07 7D 89 78 3E 13 DC
"Time": 2005-06-07 03:54:28
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    renegotiation_info  00
    server_name www.website.com
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    elliptic_curves secp521r1 [0x19], secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
Ciphers: 
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

The response from the proxy to the .NET client here is:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 642

[Your system policy has denied access to the requested URL.]
```

While IE receives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls
Cipher: Aes256 256bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha1 160bits
Key Exchange: RsaKeyX 2048bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[...]
```

I should also mention that the website I'm connecting to is our own ASP.NET website hosted on an external server. I assumed the problem was with the proxy and not with the remote server, since all requests work if I connect without the proxy. However, I can also get through by skipping the HTTPS connection using an ordinary HTTP URI.

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you provide the log from Fiddler (with stripping or replacing any credentials and IP addresses)?

Comment: Sounds like a question for you SysOp.  Ask them what the proxy policies are and that will get you a step closer.

Comment: @Dan-o Thanks. I was afraid of that. I'll get back to you if/when I manage to get something out of them. :)

Comment: According to IT service, the proxy "might" be blocking all unknown programs from internet access via SSL. So I guess I'm stuck with that. I appreciate all your advice.

Comment: Last try :) I'm wondering how the external proxy could possibly know which application connects to it? What is strange to me is that proxy sends a Set-Cookie header - what does it include? It might be a dumb guess but maybe try adding CookieContainer to your .NET request. Does it change anything?

Finally you may try switching to HTTP/1.0: `request.ProtocolVersion=HttpVersion.Version10` and observe what's happening.

Comment: @lowleveldesign Thanks for the suggestions. The cookie is BCSI-CS-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=2, which seems to be something that the Blue Coat proxy adds: http://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/BCSI-CS-xxxxxxxxxxx/4 The cookie is always the same, and is retained during the SSL handshake by both .NET and IE. Setting `request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()` doesn't make any difference. I've already tried to set HTTP/1.0. It only seems to apply to the actual request, and we never get that far due to the failed authentication; the CONNECT message uses HTTP/1.1 regardless.